# Simple Schema Meteor - Array Validation

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I am using this package to validate data before going into a database collection. One field in my collection must contain an array of strings - how can I validate this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What package are you using, and what does your code look like? Please provide more information and I am sure the community would like to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourCollection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  yourArray: {type: [String]},
});
```